# Get Max date by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write a simple query to get the MAX **DEMAND_DATE** for each **INV_CART_ID**. Here is my existing query:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_CART_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY, DEMAND_DATE
FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV A
WHERE A.INV_ITEM_ID = 1
AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
AND A.CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0
ORDER BY DEMAND_DATE DESC
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Desired Output:**

```
BUSINESS_UNIT  INV_CART_ID     INV_ITEM_ID     CART_COUNT_QTY    DEMAND_DATE
11MMS          405              1               5.0000           2018-05-29
11MMS          OUTPT_INFUSION   1               4.0000           2018-05-29
11MMS          938              1               15.0000          2018-05-31
11MMS          286              1               1.0000           2018-05-07
11MMS          708              1               4.0000           2018-04-05
```

This is what I have tried doing so far:

```
SELECT MAX(DEMAND_DATE) AS DEMAND_DATE, INV_CART_ID, BUSINESS_UNIT, 
 INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY
FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV A
WHERE A.INV_ITEM_ID = 1
 AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
 AND A.CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0
 AND A.DEMAND_DATE IN (SELECT MAX (DEMAND_DATE) FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV B 
   WHERE A.INV_ITEM_ID = B.INV_ITEM_ID GROUP BY INV_CART_ID)
GROUP BY INV_CART_ID, BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY
```

However it doesn't return all **INV_CART_ID** #'s and is not retrieving the correct row (wrong **DEMAND_DATE**):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_CART_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY, DEMAND_DATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INV_CART_ID ORDER BY DEMAND_DATE DESC) rn
    FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV
    WHERE
        INV_ITEM_ID = 1 AND
        BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' AND
        CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0
)

SELECT
    BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_CART_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY, DEMAND_DATE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY DEMAND_DATE DESC;
```

If you don't want to use analytic functions, then I still would not use your current approach.  Instead, I would join to a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.BUSINESS_UNIT,
    t1.INV_CART_ID,
    t1.INV_ITEM_ID,
    t1.CART_COUNT_QTY,
    t1.DEMAND_DATE
FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT INV_CART_ID, MAX(DEMAND_DATE) AS MAX_DEMAND_DATE
    FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV
    WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = 1 AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' AND CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0
    GROUP BY INV_CART_ID
) t2
    ON t1.INV_CART_ID = t2.INV_CART_ID AND t1.DEMAND_DATE = t2.MAX_DEMAND_DATE
WHERE
    t1.INV_ITEM_ID = 1 AND
    t1.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' AND
    t1.CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0;
```

The issue with your current query, even once corrected, is that it is using a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  These are known to be potential performance killers, and so should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Your first solution with the CTE works great! However I was looking to avoid CTE's as I need to put the SQL logic in a tool that doesnt support it. I tried your second solution with the subquery, however I am getting too many rows. I tried adding the WHERE condition to the bottom of this query (after the INNER JOIN) but then I only get one row retrieved, not one row per INV_CART_ID. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @Nick I omitted your `WHERE` criteria in my second query due to carelessness.  I _think_ the second query should work for you now.

Comment: Tim awesome! Works as expected! Thanks, will mark as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want :

```
SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_CART_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY, DEMAND_DATE
FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV AS a
WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = 1 AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' AND 
      CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0 AND
      DEMAND_DATE = (SELECT MAX(b.DEMAND_DATE)
                     FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV as b
                     WHERE a.INV_CART_ID = b.INV_CART_ID
                    );
```

However, this would gives you duplicate records, if you want to avoid duplicates then you can use `identity` column or `pk` instead in `WHERE` clause :

```
. . .
WHERE pk = (SELECT TOP (1) b.pk
            FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV as b
            WHERE a.INV_CART_ID = b.INV_CART_ID
            ORDER BY b.DEMAND_DATE DESC
           );
```

Comment: I tried your first solution however it only returns back one row (appears to be the max demand date in the entire table, and not per INV_CART_ID)

Comment: @Nick. . . That's not possible unless you have query implemented in wrong way.

Comment: Here is the query you suggested (with the WHERE criteria added): `SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_CART_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY, DEMAND_DATE
FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV AS a
WHERE a.INV_ITEM_ID = 1
   AND a.BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'
   AND a.CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0

 AND
      DEMAND_DATE = (SELECT MAX(b.DEMAND_DATE)
                     FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV as b
                     WHERE a.INV_CART_ID = b.INV_CART_ID AND
                           a.BUSINESS_UNIT = b.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    );`
With this I am only getting back one row.

Comment: @Nick. .  Might be you don' need `BUSINESS_UNIT` in subquery since you are filtering only one in outer query with `BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS'` Check edited.

Comment: You didnt edit the first SQL statement? Thats the one I am trying to use.

Comment: @Nick. . . I edited both parts or i have just neglate `BUSINESS_UNIT` in subquery.

Comment: I'm running the (edited) first SQL statement (`SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INV_CART_ID, INV_ITEM_ID, CART_COUNT_QTY, DEMAND_DATE
FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV AS a
WHERE INV_ITEM_ID = 1 AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '11MMS' AND 
      CART_COUNT_QTY <> 0 AND
      DEMAND_DATE = (SELECT MAX(b.DEMAND_DATE)
                     FROM PS_CART_CT_INF_INV as b
                     WHERE a.INV_CART_ID = b.INV_CART_ID
                    );` and I am still only retrieving back a single row. I would expect the see the max DEMAND_DATE row for each INV_CART_ID.